# How to fix logger randomly logging on the same line, even though it is set to start each log with a new line

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j to log events in java code. I have it set to start each log line as new line, with timestamp, thread, log level and the class where the log runs. So the configuration looks like this:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    logger = loggerContext.getLogger("com.asdf");
    logger.setAdditive(true);

    PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
    encoder.setPattern("%-5level %d [%thread:%M:%caller{1}]: %message%n");
    encoder.start();

    cucumberAppender = new CucumberAppender();
    cucumberAppender.setName("cucumber-appender");
    cucumberAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
    cucumberAppender.setScenario(scenario);
    cucumberAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
    cucumberAppender.start();

    logger.addAppender(cucumberAppender);
    loggerContext.start();

    logger().info("*********************************************");
    logger().info("*  Starting Scenario - {}", scenario.getName());
    logger().info("*********************************************\n");
}

@After
public void showScenarioResult(Scenario scenario) throws InterruptedException {

    logger().info("**************************************************************");
    logger().info("*  {} Scenario - {} ", scenario.getStatus(), scenario.getName());
    logger().info("**************************************************************\n");

    cucumberAppender.writeToScenario();
    cucumberAppender.stop();
    logger.detachAppender(cucumberAppender);
    logger.detachAndStopAllAppenders();
}
```

which most of the times outputs the log correctly, as so:

```
15:59:25.448 [main] INFO com.asdf.runner.steps.StepHooks -
********************************************* 15:59:25.449 [main] INFO com.asdf.runner.steps.StepHooks - *  Starting Scenario - Check Cache 15:59:25.450 [main] INFO com.asdf.runner.steps.StepHooks -
********************************************* 15:59:25.558 [main] DEBUG org.cache2k.core.util.Log - New instance, using SLF4J logging 15:59:25.575 [main] INFO org.cache2k.core.Cache2kCoreProviderImpl - cache2k starting. version=1.0.1.Final, build=undefined, defaultImplementation=HeapCache 15:59:25.629 [main] DEBUG org.cache2k.CacheManager:default - open name=default, id=wvl973, classloaderId=6us14y
```

However, sometimes the next line of the logger is written on the above one, without using the new line, like below:

```
15:59:27.353 [main] INFO com.asdf.cache.CacheService - Creating a cache for [Kafka] service with specific types.15:59:27.354 [main] INFO com.asdf.runner.steps.StepHooks - **************************************************************
15:59:27.354 [main] INFO com.asdf.runner.steps.StepHooks - *  PASSED Scenario - Check Cache 
15:59:27.354 [main] INFO com.asdf.runner.steps.StepHooks - **************************************************************
```

As you can see, the first StepHooks line goes on the same line as CacheService, which is unaesthetic.

What can i change in order for the log to always log in new line, without exceptions like this?

Comment: uhh put \n in the begin of the first line?

Comment: @rafuru it has new line as a configuration with %n, otherwise it would not show correctly for so many lines.